# How does the iOS application know what's at root if it's sandboxed?

Tags: ios, iphone, sandbox

If an application is sandboxed, it shouldn't be able to know what's outside of its own container, no?

> NSArray* dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
>   contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/" error:NULL];

yields results, but

> NSArray* dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
>   contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/var" error:NULL];
>   yields nil.

How can an app know what's at the lowest level, but no know what's at one level higher?

Comment: Different directories can have different access privileges.

Comment: Is there a way to look at a access privileges for each path?

Comment: In the sandbox everything outside of your container is none of your business. 

Comment: Except the root apparently, right?

Comment: You are seeing the root of your sandbox, not the root of your device